# rShiny custom css javascript sliders - how to get values from it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

for my app I need proportion slider (multi-thumb slider) which sums up to 100%. As I know there is nothing like that in rShiny, but I found excatly what I want here: https://codepen.io/sim04ful/pen/QWjpLJm

This is prepared in truescript and React. I downloaded the zip, and used script.js, style.css and index.html to put it into my shiny app. I made some minor changes in the code to customize and then I used iframe and html output in shiny.

It works good: https://tomaszwojtas.pl/shiny/slider_demo/ (my personal vps)
[image]

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
options(shiny.sanitize.errors = F)
 
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(width = 12,
            fluidRow(width = 12, 
                tags$head(includeScript('script.js', 'type' = 'text/javascript', 'data-unique-tag' = 'unique')),
                tags$head(includeCSS('style.css')),
                htmlOutput('prop_slider')
            ),
           
        ),

        # main panel ----
        mainPanel(width = 12, 
                  h3("I need values of the slider above to interact with :)")
        )
))
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$prop_slider <-  renderUI({
        tags$iframe(src = './index.html', width = '100%', height = 120, frameBorder="0")
    })
    
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However I have no idea how to get values from this slider. I scoped the html via Chrome, and it can be acquired from the html code:
[image]

However I have no idea how to make it alive and usable for further calculations. I will be grateful for any help...

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible with an `iframe`. The 'shinyWidgets' package provides the noUiSlider, which allows multi-thumbs. But the results is not as pretty.

Comment: Stéphane Laurent, thank you, it really helped me. I used that and stacked bar to visualize it. I will post it soon.
However... really We cannot make it working? Maybe some workaround to make xml file, and parse it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around using Stéphane Laurent suggestion. I used noUiSlider and ggplot with ggraph to visualise it.
I added some extra stuff like spinner when loading.

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(ggmap)

options(shiny.sanitize.errors = F)


ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(width = 12,

            noUiSliderInput("prop_slider2", label = "Set the structure:", min = 0, max = 100, value = c(25,50,75), step = 1, connect = c(T, T, T, T), color = "darkred", tooltips = T, width = "100%"),
            ggiraphOutput("profile_percentage", height = 150,width = "100%") %>% withSpinner(),
            
        ),

        mainPanel(width = 12, 
                  ""
        )
))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
    output$prop_slider <-  renderUI({
        tags$iframe(src = './index.html', width = '100%', height = 120, frameBorder="0")
    })
    
    profile_df <- reactive({
        profile_df <- data.frame(Home = 100 - input$prop_slider2[3], 
                                 Nomad = input$prop_slider2[3] - input$prop_slider2[2],
                                 Blended = input$prop_slider2[2] - input$prop_slider2[1],
                                 Office = input$prop_slider2[1])
        profile_df
    })
    
    output$profile_percentage <- renderggiraph({
        

        profile_df <- profile_df()

        
        profile_df_gather <- gather(profile_df, "Profile", "Value") %>% mutate(
            Value = Value/sum(Value, na.rm = T),
            Value = round(Value, 2), 
            Profile = factor(Profile, levels=c("Home", "Nomad", "Blended", "Office"),ordered=T),
            Definition = rep("Some info", 4))
      
        
        p1 <- profile_df_gather %>%
            ggplot(., aes(1, Value, fill = Profile)) + 
            geom_bar_interactive(aes(tooltip = Definition), stat = "identity") +
            coord_flip() + 
            theme_nothing() +
            theme(plot.margin = unit(-c(1,2,1,1.6), "cm")) +
            scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds") +
            geom_text_interactive(aes(label = paste0(Profile,": ", Value*100, "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
        gp1 <- girafe(ggobj = p1, width_svg = 15, height_svg = 0.5)
        
        
        ggp1<- girafe_options(gp1,
                              
                              fonts = list(sans = "Helvetica"), opts_sizing(rescale = T, width = 1),
                              opts_toolbar(saveaspng = F))
        ggp1
    })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

and here is live version: https://tomaszwojtas.pl/shiny/slider_demo_2/